# Desreferência de uma referência possivelmente nula NET6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, warnings, dotnet-cli

Boa tarde ao fazer um a implementação de IRepository em uma api no NET6 fui suprendido com esse warning "Desreferência de uma referência possivelmente nula." como mostrado abaixo e não sei como posso estar resolvendo
[Desreferência de uma referência possivelmente nula.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bno8M.png)

codigo :

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
private readonly MysqlContext ?_context;
private readonly IMapper ?_mapper;

```
    public ProductRepository( MysqlContext context ,IMapper mapper)
    {
        _context = context;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<ProductVO>> FindAll()
    {
        List<Product> products = await _context.Products.ToListAsync(); //ERRO SE DA NESSAS LINHAS
        return _mapper.Map<List<ProductVO>>(products); //ERRO SE DA NESSAS LINHAS
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que você está utilizando a versão 8 do c#. Conforme documentação da Microsoft.

> O C# 8 introduziu um novo recurso chamado [NRT (tipos de referência
> anuláveis)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types), permitindo que tipos de referência sejam anotados,
> indicando se é válido que eles contenham nulo ou não.

Para solucionar este problema, é necessário inicializar o `DbSet` no seu `DbContext`.

Exemplo:

```cs
public DbSet<Customer> Customers => Set<Customer>();
```

Maiores detalhes podem ser encontrado na [documentação do ef core](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types#dbcontext-and-dbset).

Comment: Muito obrigado!!, ajudo bastante resolvi o problema mais infelizmente por não ter reputação o suficiente não posso marcar sua resposta como válida